# Excel - how can i use the Filter formula to account for the next month?

Tags: excel, date, filter

i made use of the FILTER formula to bring me data that falls in the same month as TODAY:
=FILTER(Data!N2:N22,MONTH(Money!C29)=MONTH(Data!M2:M22))

I'm now trying to do the exact same, except for the next month

i've been toying around with different variations of the EDATE function, but can't get it to work.  I keep getting a #CALC! error:
=FILTER(Data!N2:N22,EDATE(MONTH(Money!C29),1)=MONTH(Data!M2:M22))

i've also tried this formula, which does return values, but it returns data for all months in my table, as opposed to just next month's:

=FILTER(Data!N2:N22,(MONTH(EDATE(Money!C29,1)=MONTH(Data!M2:M22))))

please let me know if you would like more clarification

**edit - not really sure how to add sample data here

Data Sheet

| M | N | O |
| --- | --- | --- |

| Due | Frequency | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |

| 2 -2 | Annual | Home |
| --- | --- | --- |

| 1 -27 | Monthly | Car |
| --- | --- | --- |

| 2 -25 | Annual | Retail |
| --- | --- | --- |

Money Sheet (where the formula exists)

C29 = TODAY()

Comment: except next month, then filter till last day of current month. They you could try to use `=EOMONTH()` function. Also please add some sample data here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to use `EOMONTH` function.

For this month, something like (where `Dates` refers to your column of dates):

```
=FILTER(myArray,(Dates>EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1))*(Dates<=EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)))
```

and for next month:

```
=FILTER(myArray,(Dates>EOMONTH(TODAY(),0))*(Dates<=EOMONTH(TODAY(),1)))
```

You'll have to replace `myArray` and `Dates` with whatever is appropriate for your data.

Comment: not sure if i'm doing something wrong or if my Dates column is not getting read in date format....is it possible that i can send you my file?

Comment: @maestro If you are working with dates, it is important they be real dates.  One way to tell is to see if the `ISTEXT` function returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`.  Should return `FALSE` for a real date.  Another method is to see if you can apply differing date formats to the cell. If the appearance doesn't change, then they are not real dates. Your screenshot, posted after I posted my suggestion, makes me wonder if your dates are really text strings, in which case this formula will not work.

Comment: toyed around with it, but i'm getting a #CALC! error now
.  just saw your comment, ISTEXT returns TRUE.  are you able to change your formula to read it as a date?

currently using: =FILTER(Data!N2:N22,(Data!M2:M22>EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1))*(Data!M2:M22<=EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)))

Comment: @maestro That will occur if there are no valid dates in the specified range.

Comment: ah, i think it's working now...used DATEVALUE...let me try both your formulas now

Comment: oh man, this is beautiful...thanks so much.  i wanted to also do this with a date range input in two cells...i'll try to do it on my own but may come back and add a comment here if it doesn't work

Comment: so beautiful...looks like this gets done everything i needed...thanks again man

=FILTER(Table1[Frequency],(DATEVALUE(Table1[Due])>DATEVALUE(C73))*(DATEVALUE(Table1[Due])<=DATEVALUE(D73)))